# Angular2 detect change in service

Tags: angular

I have one component in Angular2 which is changing a "lang" class variable in my service translate.service.ts. In another component I am fetching a dict with the translation on init. If the first component changes the services language later, I want to refetch the dict in the second component automatically. How do I do that?

First component:

```
  setLang(lang) {
    this._translateService.setLang(lang);
  }
```

Service:

```
dict = { "en": {}};
lang = "en";

setLang(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
}

getLang() {
    return this.dict;
}
```

Second component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dict = this._translateService.getDict();
}
```

Comment: In the service, do you modify `dict` or do you replace it?  If you only modify it, the second component will automatically get/see the changes because it has a reference to the `dict` object (not a copy).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Edit:**

Following the [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215945/mark-rajcok)'s comment, a `Subject` / `Observable` should be preferred:

> EventEmitter should only be used for emitting custom Events in components, and that we should use Rx for other observable/event scenarios.

**Original Answer:**

You should use an `EventEmitter` in the service:

```
export class LangService {
  langUpdated:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  setLang(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    this.langUpdated.emit(this.lang);
  }

  getLang() {
    return this.dict;
  }
}
```

Components could subscribe on this event to be notified when the `lang` property is updated.

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private _translateService:LangService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._translateService.langUpdated.subscribe(
      (lang) => {
        this.dict = this._translateService.getDict();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924#35568924)
- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436#34402436)

Comment: With that said, you can use Subject.next() which is pretty much what [EventEmitter.emit](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/facade/src/async.ts#L78) does.

Comment: From what I understand EventEmitters should ONLY be used with @output?

Comment: Can you update the answer to reflect how to use Subject/Observable?

Comment: This answer definetly is correct. BUT is marked as bad practice ( YOU SHOULDN'T USE EVENT EMMITER on a service ). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380696/unable-to-figure-out-correct-eventemitter-or-observable-syntax-in-angular2-servi/33382275#comment54684990_33382275

Comment: so what's the best way then? I want to subscribe to my provider var but I want to do it inside the provider otherwise I need to change a lot of components

Comment: Any update yet?