# How to change/control button status (boolean) from the Service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to disable/enable a button in a component based on property status `false/true`. This status changes in the service based on an if-statement.

**`*.service.ts`:**

```
public connectionRetry(
    initialDelay,
    maxRetry,
    errorWhiteList,
    triggerBtn,

  ) {
    return (errors) => errors.scan((retryAttempts, error) => {
        if ( retryAttempts < maxRetry ) {
            triggerBtn = true;
        }
        if ( !errorWhiteList.includes(error.status ) || retryAttempts > maxRetry) {
            triggerBtn = false;
            throw error;
        }
        return retryAttempts + 1;
    }, 0).switchMap((retryAttempts) => {
          let delay = Math.pow(2, retryAttempts - 1) * initialDelay;
          return Observable.timer(delay);
    });
}
```

**`*.component.ts`**:

```
public isBtnDisabled = false;
constructor ( public mainService: MainService, public mainUtils: MainUtils ) {}

public storeData(paramX, paramY) {
     this.mainService.addUser(paramX, paramY)
     .retryWhen(
         this.mainUtils.connectionRetry(
         xxx, 
         xxx, 
         [xxx], 
         this.isBtnDisabled,
    ))
    .subscribe(
       res => {....},
       error = > {...}

    );
}
```

**`*.component.html`**:

`<button [disabled]="!form.valid || isBtnDisabled">button text</button>`

The issue is that I just can't make this concept working... the property `isBtnDisabled` keeps always the status: `false` in the component **`ts`** and **`html`**.

If I implement the function: `connectionRetry()` directly in the `*.component.ts`, it works straight forward, but not via the service. Has it to do with the angular digest cycle?

I have been searching (also here in SOF) and trying different approach as, but unfortunately without success. It seems to be simple actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do the usual way - through **Subject** or **BehaviorSubject**

Service:

```
public $btnSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>();
```

Now whenever you need to change false to true and vise versa, just `next(//true or false)`:

```
return (errors) => errors.scan((retryAttempts, error) => {
   if ( retryAttempts < maxRetry ) {
       this.$btnSubject.next(true)
   }
```

And in component subscribe to that Subject:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.mainService.$btnSubject.subscribe(val => this.isBtnDisabled = val)
}
```

p.s. usual is better to keep Subject private to class scope and create another instance - `public btnSubject$ = this.$btnSubject.asObservable()` and subscribe to it.

---

**OLD POST:**

When you pass `this.isBtnDisabled` to `retryWhen()` you just pass a value of it, not the reference of an object.

I am not sure at what time you want to set `isBtnDisabled` to true, so maybe there is a better way, but this also, i assume is OK - you can simply reference to that `isBtnDisabled`:

```
.subscribe(
  res => {this.triggerBtn = this.mainService.triggerBtn }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right... in tis case I'm passing just the status/value in this case without reference to the element. Have been also trying `@ViewChild('mainBtn') mainBtn: ElementRef;` and then changing the status, but it didn't help.The button should be disabled as long as request is try to connect to the server. When the retry ends e.g. with a failed connection (can't reach the server), then should be back to enabled in order the let the user clicks once again.

Comment: Yes, thats confusing at first, but later it makes sense.

Comment: ...in this case your suggestion won't work as expected, as both cases must happen before `subscribe() {...}`

Comment: Ok, I added another option

Comment: Good idea. I was right now looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869406/angular2-detect-change-in-service). I'll give it a try.

Comment: In that question's answer they use EventEmitter - its another way to pass data, but its best for parent-component - child-component relation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170303/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-from-zero-to-hero).

Comment: It works implementing the second option... Just one small thing has to change/be updated. The construction function `BehaviorSubject()` expects a parameter, so therefore I changed it to: `public $btnSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);`