# Angular 2 Component Interaction via a service

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs, observable, angular-directive

I have two parallel directives (as apposed to parent-child) and I want them to communicate via a service using observable if possible. I've read the [official component interaction guidline](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service), but it talks about parent-child interaction. I tried to make a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CxrEwkrJgXETq5lBX6Of?p=preview) with two directives but it doesn't work.

Basically, what I want is to create a service:

```
export class DirService {
   contentSource = new Subject();
   content$ = this.contentSource.asObservable();
}
```

And then, use this service to make a bridge between < dir1 > and < dir2 >. Could someone point out how to implement this senerio?

Btw, I choose to use observable mainly because:

- I read the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380696/unable-to-figure-out-correct-eventemitter-or-observable-syntax-in-angular2-servi#comment54684990_33382275) in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380696/unable-to-figure-out-correct-eventemitter-or-observable-syntax-in-angular2-servi).
- If I want many directives to communicate, I guess observable could make the logic more clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the "shared" service to `providers` of each component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dir2',
    template: '{{field}}',
    providers: [DirService]
})
```

then for each component a new instance is maintained.

To get a shared service you either add it only in `bootstrap(AppComponent, [DirService])` or one common ancestor of the components and directives that defines the root component and the scope of the shared service.
This way every descendant gets the same instance.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KhpqG45RDpOelexreOWt?p=preview)

See also
- [AngularJs 2 - multiple instance of service created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929665/angularjs-2-multiple-instance-of-service-created/34929697#34929697)
- [How to use Dependency Injection (DI) correctly in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109555/how-to-use-dependency-injection-di-correctly-in-angular2/36111307#36111307)

Comment: thx! And here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5PQ9AmbfNVDHfWIW54mN?p=preview) using common ancestor based on you advice.

Comment: Well said! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `DirService` service when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ DirService ]);
```

And remove it from component providers attribute:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  //providers: [ DirService ]
})
```

This way you will share the same instance of the service for the whole application (and both components).

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rYq3iicbd4mKGyxHlJmg?p=preview.

This behavior is linked to the "hierarchical injectors" of Angular2 dependency injection.

For more details, you could have a look at this question:

- [What's the best way to inject one service into another in angular 2 (Beta)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804298/whats-the-best-way-to-inject-one-service-into-another-in-angular-2-beta/34807397)