# Why do [class.someClass] and [ngClass] bindings work differently with myObservable$ | async?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an element I want to apply a certain class to, so I used a [class.active] conditional that is watching an Observable changes. But when I toggle it doesn't apply to the following `li` and breaks down the whole app:

`<li *ngFor="let room of activeRooms$ | async" [class.active]="room.name === (currentRoomName$ | async)">`

I found that if i use to [ngClass] instead, it works perfectly:

`<li *ngFor="let room of activeRooms$ | async" [ngClass]="{ active: room.name === (currentRoomName$ | async)}">`

Why is that? Can anyone throw some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell for sure, but just couple ideas what you could check:

- Change Observable to EventEmitter, they perform slightly differently; you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380696/unable-to-figure-out-correct-eventemitter-or-observable-syntax-in-angular2-servi) for more information.
- Observable event can be generated somewhere outside of angular NgZone; in that case, you'd need to inject it in your component and update your property through something like this:

  `zone.run(() => this.prop = newValue);`

This way angular would see your changes which it would not have been able to see otherwise. You can read more about zones here: [another link](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html)